# setState react to generate array result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How to push index into array position on an onChange event? Let's assume user can type on any of the input, and I can get the values in array, the position must be matched with the index of the input

```
onChange = () => {
    //so that I get, console.log(this.state.inputGroup)
    //expected ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <input onChange={e => this.onChange(1, index)} type="text"/>
            <input onChange={e => this.onChange(2, index)} type="text"/>
            <input onChange={e => this.onChange(3, index)} type="text"/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This is too fragmentary for us to usefully help. (What's `this.state.inputGroup` for instance? Why do you need input indexes? Etc. Don't just answer *those* questions, please provide a complete explanation.) Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass value from input to `onChange` method. 
So you pass `e.target.value`. Fixed indexes are first argument and that is how you point to array index.

`<input onChange={(e) => { this.onChange(1, e.target.value) }} type="text"/>`

and in `onChange` method

```
onChange = (inputIndex, textValue) => {
   //I assume that array of size equal to inputs quantity already is 
   //declared with ex. empty strings (you can initialize that in 
   //component constructor)

   const inputGroup = this.state.inputGroup
   inputGroup[inputIndex] = textValue

   this.setState({ inputGroup })
}
```

And btw. you probably want to start your inputs indexation with 0 :) Otherwise 0 element of your array will never be used by any of the inputs.

Comment: Why downvote?:) I believe this is precisely what OP wanted. Let him talk before downvoting :|

Comment: First index can be first or second argument, secondly your inputGroup is constant how you can modify it?

Comment: `const` array is OK to be there. It cannot be overwriten as a whole object, but its parts can well be written/read. `const` dont make objects immutable. I don`t get first part of your comment though. How can first index be first or second? I defined the method so it is first argument and pass it as first. How come can it be second?

Comment: there, appreciated it

Comment: appreacte this!

Comment: sure thing! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      inputGroup: [null, null, null]
    }
  }

  onChange(index, e) {
    const inputGroupState = this.state.inputGroup;
    inputGroupState[index] = e.target.value;

    this.setState({
        inputGroup: inputGroupState
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.inputGroup)
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
       <input onChange = {e => this.onChange(0, e)} type = "text" / >
       <input onChange = {e => this.onChange(1, e)} type = "text" / >
       <input onChange = {e => this.onChange(2, e)} type = "text" / >
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < Test / > , document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```